# Cannot get the user to input text in my EditView for android

Tags: android, input, android-widget

I'm doing some basic programming for my android in eclipse

I'm trying to do something simple as getting the user to enter a name in an `EditText`, but when I press the textbox the soft keyboard doesn't appear and input is impossible.

I don't know if I have forgotten anything in the code or anything else,
this is what I have so far:

```
public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private EditText enterName;
    private Button accept;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        enterName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        accept = (Button)findViewById(R.id.acceptName);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
```

And the layout .XML-file

```
...
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:hint="Enter Name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
...
```

So at the moment all I want is to get the user to be able to write text in the box.

EDIT:---->New Problem---->

Ok, so last problem involved something that I didn't mention in the post.

In my activity I change the layout with command:

```
setContentView(R.id.(XML-file));
```

And when I put the EditView in the second XML (not the one that shows on create) it wont work =/. Sorry if I left this out before, but does it make any sense?

Comment: perhaps you forgot a "}" since I see you have the onClick method inside your onCreate.
and also you can find view tutorials here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Comment: Also I tested your code and it works fine, just keep in mind that if your Android device has a phisical keyboard, the softkeyboard will not appear.

Comment: oh yea, the "}" just didn't make the post ^^, thanks for trying it, I'm happy it's working. And my phone doesn't have a phys keyboard either =/. 

Could it have something to do with the system(2.1)? Too old? =)

And the tutorial is great too for me atm =D, I just don't know what too try to fix with this then =/ havn't really got access to another phone to try it on either =( hmm...

Comment: It seems that I found the problem. And it was is something that I didn't mention in the post =///

But a new problem came up isntead, uhm...im gonna try and edit the original post=)

Comment: so you change your layout on runtime? Maybe having a bit more of your code could help since I dont see you changing that layout in your current code. And therefore cannot see if its something to be with or not.